# mismatched types in Pallet

Tags: rust, substrate, pallet

The error is shown when i follow step to expose the contracts pallet api.

https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet-to-your-runtime/#install-the-node-template

I followed the steps all the way and fixed another error that was associating the ContractExecResult::Success. Now i have trouble with these 2 errors.

I believe it has something to do with its syntax or maybe an updated library api that the tutorial has not updated to yet.

```
$ cargo check -p node-template-runtime
   Compiling node-template-runtime v2.0.0-rc5 (C:\substrate-node-template2\runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v2.0.0-rc5 (C:\substrate-node-template2\runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\substrate-node-template2\target\debug\build\node-template-runtime-8af1699a702fd7e8\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=C:\\substrate-node-template2\\target\\debug\\wbuild\\node-template-runtime\\Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--release"

--- stderr
   Compiling wasm-build-runner-impl v1.0.0 (C:\substrate-node-template2\target\debug\wbuild-runner\node-template-runtime6610820868370414452)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.75s
     Running `C:\substrate-node-template2\target\debug\wbuild-runner\node-template-runtime6610820868370414452\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\debug\wasm-build-runner-impl.exe`
   Compiling node-template-runtime v2.0.0-rc5 (C:\substrate-node-template2\runtime)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\substrate-node-template2\runtime\src\lib.rs:477:17
    |
476 |             match exec_result {
    |                   ----------- this expression has type `(core::result::Result<pallet_contracts::ExecReturnValue, sp_runtime::DispatchError>, u64)`
477 |                 Ok(v) => ContractExecResult::Success{
    |                 ^^^^^ expected tuple, found enum `core::result::Result`
    |
    = note: expected tuple `(core::result::Result<pallet_contracts::ExecReturnValue, sp_runtime::DispatchError>, u64)`
                found enum `core::result::Result<_, _>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> C:\substrate-node-template2\runtime\src\lib.rs:482:17
    |
476 |             match exec_result {
    |                   ----------- this expression has type `(core::result::Result<pallet_contracts::ExecReturnValue, sp_runtime::DispatchError>, u64)`
...
482 |                 Err(_) => ContractExecResult::Error,
    |                 ^^^^^^ expected tuple, found enum `core::result::Result`
    |
    = note: expected tuple `(core::result::Result<pallet_contracts::ExecReturnValue, sp_runtime::DispatchError>, u64)`
                found enum `core::result::Result<_, _>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `node-template-runtime`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `C:\substrate-node-template2\target\debug\wbuild-runner\node-template-runtime6610820868370414452\target\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\debug\wasm-build-runner-impl.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

here is the code that is in runtime\src\lib.rs that the tutorial had me add that is causing the issue, and my modified code where 'flags' and 'gas_consumed' is added and 'status' was removed.

```
 /*** Add This Block ***/
    impl contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi<Block, AccountId, Balance, BlockNumber>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn call(
            origin: AccountId,
            dest: AccountId,
            value: Balance,
            gas_limit: u64,
            input_data: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> ContractExecResult {
            let exec_result =
                Contracts::bare_call(origin, dest.into(), value, gas_limit, input_data);
            match exec_result {
                Ok(v) => ContractExecResult::Success{
                flags: v.status,
                data: v.data,
                gas_consumed: v.gas_consumed,
                },
                Err(_) => ContractExecResult::Error,
            }
        }

        fn get_storage(
            address: AccountId,
            key: [u8; 32],
        ) -> contracts_primitives::GetStorageResult {
            Contracts::get_storage(address, key)
        }

        fn rent_projection(
            address: AccountId,
        ) -> contracts_primitives::RentProjectionResult<BlockNumber> {
            Contracts::rent_projection(address)
        }
    }
   /*** End Added Block ***/
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, it looks like you are using version 2.0.0-rc5 of the node template. At the moment, the Contracts pallet tutorial is up-to-date as of v2.0.0-rc4. Can you clone the node template from that branch and use that as a starting point? `git clone -b v2.0.0-rc4 --depth 1 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template`

Answer (score 0):

Starting v2.0.0-rc5, the bare_call function in Contracts pallet returns ExecResult and Gas, which can be seen at [line 633](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/be8bb186d87b9d2b47a2907c9b51ae1e252362c3/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L633), whereas only ExecResult is returned on the previous version of the Contracts pallet.

In order to continue with the tutorial, I did some tweaks with the provided code snippet in the tutorial. Here's the version of my code.

```
fn call(
        origin: AccountId,
        dest: AccountId,
        value: Balance,
        gas_limit: u64,
        input_data: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> ContractExecResult {
        let exec_result =
            Contracts::bare_call(origin, dest.into(), value, gas_limit, input_data);
        match exec_result {
            (Ok(v), gas) => ContractExecResult::Success {
                flags: v.flags.bits(),
                data: v.data,
                gas_consumed: gas,
            },
            (Err(_), _) => ContractExecResult::Error,
        }
    }
```

Note: I'm fairly new with Rust so my code is probably not the most optimal solution.